# Python pipe.send() hangs on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, pipe, freeze

Following program always hangs on `Mac OS` (Python 2.7.5) if I return big enough string on Mac OS. I can't says for sure what is the limit, but it works for smaller text.
It works fine on `Ubuntu`, but hangs on `pipe_to_parent.send(result)`.

Does anybody know how to fix this? Is there anything wrong with the code bellow?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe


def run(text, length):
    return (text * ((length / len(text))+1))[:length]

def proc_func(pipe_to_parent):
    result = {'status': 1, 'log': run('Hello World', 20000), 'details': {}, 'exception': ''}
    pipe_to_parent.send(result)
    sys.exit()


def call_run():
    to_child, to_self = Pipe()

    proc = Process(target=proc_func, args=(to_self,))
    proc.start()
    proc.join()
    print(to_child.recv())
    to_child.close()
    to_self.close()

call_run()
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) shows examples that have some differences to yours: 1. the target function (`proc_func`) calls `.close()` on the received pipe, instead of doing `sys.exit`, 2. the parent calls `.recv()` before doing `.join()`

Comment: Well, pipe is closed anyway, I don't think it's related. With regards to the .join() - nice suggestion, send() may hang if nobody calls receive. I'll try and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: You were right, this is deadlock when calling .join() and .send(). Could you please post an answer, so I can mark it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) shows an example that has some differences, as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def f(conn):
    conn.send([42, None, 'hello'])
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()

    # This is the important part
    # Note: conn.recv() is called _before_ process.join()
    print parent_conn.recv()   # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

In your example, you call `.recv()` *after* you've already called `process.join()`.

```
...
proc = Process(target=proc_func, args=(to_self,))
proc.start()
proc.join()
print(to_child.recv())
...
```

To see exactly what is happening, we would have to look at the `multiprocessing` module code, but I'm guessing that the hanging is occurring because the pipe is attempting to begin a read from a closed end and blocking to wait for a response.

Comment: When I'm calling `send()` pipe is not closed yet in my example, because I'm closing both pipes in the main process after `join()` returns. I guess `send()` blocks until `recv()` is called for some reason on `OSX`, but `recv()` is not called while process is not finished, so deadlock happens.

Comment: Also it's interesting to note, that it doesn't hang if the string returned is small.

Comment: @incognito, seeing the same behavior - I realize this is 6 years old (!), but still interesting to me _why_ that happens